# android - How to enable a next level on a Quiz?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android app development, I'm doing a quiz app, that has categories and levels, and I have to leave only the first level of each category enabled, the next level is enabled when the user answers the question correctly, but, I don't know how to do this. Could you help me? P.S.: My database has three tables: category, level and questions. I already got it show the questions to the user and pass the questions. Below is my code:

```
public void verifyAnswer(String answer){
    if(qCurrent.getAnswer().equals(answer)){
        if(qid<5){
            qCurrent = qList.get(qid);
            setQuestions();
        }
        else{
            showMsgWin();
                    //here the code to unlock the next level
                    Button level2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel2);
                    level2.setEnabled(true);        
        } 
    }
    else {
        showMsgLose();
    }   
}
```

My activityLevels:

```
    ImageButton  btnNivel1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel1);
    ImageButton  btnNivel2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel2);
    ImageButton  btnNivel3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel3);
    ImageButton  btnNivel4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel4);
    ImageButton  btnNivel5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel5);
    ImageButton  btnNivel6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNivel6);

    btnNivel1.setEnabled(true);
    btnNivel2.setEnabled(false);
    btnNivel3.setEnabled(false);
    btnNivel4.setEnabled(false);
    btnNivel5.setEnabled(false);
    btnNivel6.setEnabled(false);
```

Error:

```
10-06 03:56:15.382: E/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 03:56:15.382: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What does it mean in your application to unlock a new level? Do you need to store something in the database? Shared preferences?

Comment: @Szymon Sorry! I have an image button that's disabled, and i need to enable the image button after the user answer the questions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Initially Disable click listener for all levels other then 1 like this assuming level1,level2,level3 & level4 are your buttons.

```
    btnNivel2.setEnabled(false);
    btnNivel3.setEnabled(false);
    btnNivel4.setEnabled(false);
```

then enable the rest of them

```
else{
            showMsgWin();
                    //here the code to unlock the next level


    btnNivel2.setEnabled(true);
    //btnNivel3.setEnabled(true);
    //btnNivel4.setEnabled(true);

        }
```

Comment: i tried this, but give me an error of nullPointerException. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public void verifyAnswer(String answer){
if(qCurrent.getAnswer().equals(answer)){
    if(qid<5){
        qCurrent = qList.get(qid);
        setQuestions();
    }
    else{
        showMsgWin();
 //enable the image button here.
 nextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
 //if you are not using any selector change the image of imagebutton
    nextLevelButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_next_level_image);
 //you can write here code for setting the next level..But it will be better to handle
               //it in the nextLevel Image button onclick action
    } 
  }
  else {
    showMsgLose();
  }   
}
```